# BASH: use a for-loop variable as another variable

Tags: bash, shell, loops, unix

I have 7K odd files on a folder which I want to organise into different folder based on the pattern of the file. I have given some dummy data and script to demonstrate the issue that I am facing. The patterns are actually more through than the ones shown in the example.

```
folder/
0001_x.dat
0002_y.dat
0003_y.dat
0004_y.dat
0005_y.dat
0006_y.dat
0007_y.dat
0008_y.dat
0009_y.dat
...
```

Now the script ...

```
#!/bin/bash 

p1="x|y|z"
p2="a|b|c"
p3="m|n|o"
FILES=$(find . -type f)

for pattern in p1 p2 p3; do 
  mkdir $pattern-folder
  echo "$FILES" | egrep $$pattern | while read file ; do mv $file $pattern-folder ; done      # << the "$$pattern" doesn't work. What should be the right syntax here ?
  done
done
```

I ended up doing it the below way, but I feel it's not clean. All healthy criticisms and suggestions are welcome.

```
for pattern in p1 p2 p3; do 
  mkdir $pattern-folder
  echo "$FILES" | egrep $p1 | while read file ; do mv $file $p1-folder
  echo "$FILES" | egrep $p2 | while read file ; do mv $file $p2-folder
  echo "$FILES" | egrep $p3 | while read file ; do mv $file $p3-folder
  done
done
```

Comment: Okay, Is your script doing exactly what you want? What exactly you want the script to do?

Answer (score 0):

```
#!/bin/bash

# make an array
PATTERNS[0]="x|y|z"
PATTERNS[1]="a|b|c"
PATTERNS[2]="m|n|o"

# iterate
for var in "${PATTERNS[@]}"
do
  echo "${var}"
  # do something
done
```

Comment: Thanks, that is just perfect ! I was just reading up and I could even try an associative array and store everything together and call what I want at each iteration .

Answer (score 0):

Although it seems like an array will work for you, you could achieve the indirect variable reference by using `"${!pattern}"` instead of `$$pattern`. (You should have double-quoted the argument to `egrep`, but ot wouldn't help because `$$` is a shell replacement (shell's pid) and not an indirect variable reference.)